# Google Maps direct url with 8 locations loaded

Tags: google-maps

What I am looking for is the specific parameters I need to go directly to google maps with 8 locations (address or lat/long coordinates) already set with driving directions.  Is something like this doable or mere pie in the sky thinking?

Comment: Is it a single route with a start, end and 6 waypoints?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [this description of available Google Maps parameters](http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters)

```
saddr: - start
daddr: - destination
to:    - waypoints
```

[example](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Hartford,+CT&daddr=New+York,+NY+to%3aNewark,+NJ+to%3aPhiladelphia,+PA+to%3aPittsburgh,PA+to%3aCleveland,OH+to%3aChicago,IL+to%3aMinneapolis,MN)