# Google URL Scheme Queries :: Waypoints

Tags: google-maps, web, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have been trying and searching all over the place to see if this even exists, I have been looking at the Google Maps iOS URL Schema, and this would be perfect for what I would need on one of my websites, BUT, the main feature of my website requires way points to be used.

For example:
[This route which contains a waypoint](https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=Unknown%20road&daddr=55.0955732,-1.9464959%20to:55.0897648,-2.2159722%20to:55.0001671,-2.0873326%20to%3aUnknown%20road&hl=en&ll=55.052023,-1.994019&spn=0.224592,0.676346&sll=55.070112,-1.934967&sspn=0.224491,0.676346&geocode=FaMKSAMdon7j_w;FRWxSAMdgUzi_yl1crxMN919SDGZyV-VYVeb_g;FWSaSAMd3C_e_ynXQ23tu799SDHOAmj0aSQUfg;FWc8RwMdXCbg_ynLkfZOlMZ9SDFceRafg1eFFw;FSl0RwMdufjh_w&t=h&mra=dpe&mrsp=3&sz=11&via=1,2,3&z=11)

Where the to and from are not a direct route.

Now I would like to be able to send the above route to the Google Maps iOS application using a URL Schema (if possible). Are there any Google Map Experts here? Or even a way to get the above into the iOS application another way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps direct url with 8 locations loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660565/google-maps-direct-url-with-8-locations-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

For both Safari & Chrome latest versions (at 2013-Jun-10th) iOS 6.0.1

The next URL scheme also works as an "href" in both browsers,
or in the Safari address bar.

maps:q=GivenTitle@latitude,longtitude